# android button click not fire inside scrollview

Tags: android, button, scrollview, listener

I have some problem with a button inside scrollview, this is my xml,

```
<ScrollView
    tools:context="com.francescovenica.remember.fragments.AddAlarmFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:text="Salva"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/saveAlarm"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

here I instantiate the buttons (I'm working with a fragment)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_alarm, container, false);

        btn_saveAlarm = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.saveAlarm);

        System.out.println("saveAlarm: " + btn_saveAlarm);

        return view;
    }
```

while this is my listener

```
btn_saveAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("click");
            }
        });
```

the click is not fire, where is the error?

EDIT -----

I find the problem but I don't understand it...

I call setUpView in activityCreated

public void setUpView(){

```
    btn_saveAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveAlarm();
        }
    });

alarm_date = Calendar.getInstance();


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    datePicker.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

            alarm_date.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            alarm_date.set(Calendar.MONTH,(month+1));
            alarm_date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);

            setTimePickerDialog();

        }
    });
}
```

I don't know why but with alarm_date = Calendar.getInstance(); the button not work, if I comment it the button work correctly....why Calendar.getInstance break all?

Comment: `btn_saveAlarm.setOnClickListener` where do you call this ?

Comment: inside onActivityCreated

Comment: the on click listener for the button should be placed BEFORE `return view`;

Comment: onActivityCreated is after onCreateView so the listener is correct!

Comment: do you have any other reference to the same button (e.g. in the activity, using the same id.) ?

Comment: did you try to put a breakpoint in the listener?

Comment: Set clickable to your ScrollView `android:clickable="true"`' in your xml

Comment: in on create view type `btn_saveAlarm.setText("on Create View")` and in the on activity created type `btn_saveAlarm.setText("On activity created")` so we know if its been bound to the fragment UI properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
    tools:context="com.francescovenica.remember.fragments.AddAlarmFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- rest of code -->
```

The `android:clickable="true"` should do the trick